# How can I get Sinatra to deliver Markdown as HTML as well as the source code as plain text?

Tags: ruby, sinatra, markdown

I'm building a simple "notes" site using Sinatra and Heroku. I write my notes up using Markdown and use the rdiscount gem to convert them to HTML in Sinatra.  So a request for /foo would serve up the template /views/foo.md, converted to HTML

What I'd also like to be able to do is serve up the Markdown source as a plain text file. So /foo/source (or something similar) would server up /views/foo.md as plain text.

I've tried using ERB but it just ends up wanting to serve /views/foo.erb.

Here is my current app:

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'rdiscount'

set :markdown, :layout_engine => :erb

get '/' do
  markdown :index
end

get '/:topic' do
  markdown params[:topic].to_sym
end
```

Comment: See my full answer, but also, this line might be messing you up: "set :markdown, :layout_engine => :erb" -- The "layout" in the "layout_engine" option uses Rails' definition of "layout" as "page wrapper" as in "use the erb engine for *layouts* when rendering markdown *templates*" and I don't see any layouts anywhere. Is that what's messing you up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a little more searching I managed to get it working using send_file:

```
get '/:topic/source' do
  send_file File.dirname(__FILE__) + "/views/#{params[:topic]}.md", :type => :text
end
```

But I'd like to believe there's a more elegant solution out there, so leaving the question open for now.

Answer (score 4):

Short answer: use `File.read` to suck in the file's contents, then do what you want with it:

```
get '/topic/:topic'
    markdown File.read(params[:topic] + ".md")
end
```

Long answer: Sinatra can get kind of goofy with dots and colons and file types, so you may have to wrest control of the parameter. The following (working!) Sinatra app may help demonstrate.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'sinatra'

get '/' do  
  markdown <<-MARKDOWN
# Markdown in Sinatra
* [markdown](/notes)
* [plain text](/notes.txt)
* [pre html](/notes.html)
  MARKDOWN
end

def source
  parts = params[:base].split('.')
  name = parts.first
  ext = parts.last
  filename = name  + ".md"
  source = File.read(filename)
  puts "filename=" + filename.inspect
  puts "source=" + source.inspect
  source
end

get '/:base.txt' do
  source
end

get '/:base.html' do
  "<pre>#{source}</pre>"
end

get '/:base' do
  markdown source
end
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try using the `str` template:

```
get '/:topic/source' do
  str params[:topic].to_sym
end
```

The only thing to take into account is that it'll try to interpolate the values like it would do with a string - in other words, it'll try to replace `#{foo}` with `foo.to_s`. This might or might not be desirable.

Disclaimer: I'm not sure it'll work, I had to deduce this functionality by looking at the source code of [Tilt](https://github.com/rtomayko/tilt), and I haven't tested it.

Edit: I'm afraid that doesn't work. It's possible to define the str method like this:

```
helpers do
  def str(*args) render(:str, *args) end
end
```

The Tilt engine tries to find a view called 'foo.str' instead of using 'foo.md'. I also tried registering 'md' as a valid extension of StringTemplate, but it didn't work (I either got the markdown rendered as a string, or I had the same error as before.

Sorry.

Comment: That generates an error: undefined method `str' for #<Sinatra::Application:0x0000010104b508>. I'm guessing there's another syntax I need to use. Still trying to figure it out.

Comment: tried more stuff, and added to my answer. However, nothing worked :/

Comment: Thanks for taking a look. For now my answer above does the trick.

Comment: You're thinking too hard. If what you want is raw text, then get the raw text and emit it. Sinatra is Ruby!